# Bootstrap modal - always same modal is called altough using right ID

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have created several modals associated to a button each, but although I have different IDs associating in this case a button or a link to the right modal, the very same modal is always the one that pops up.
I have something like this:

```
    <div class="container">

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Toy_Story.jpg" width="220" height="342">
    <h2>Toy Story</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalKYz2wyBy3kc">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> More details!
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary movie-button-play"
    data-trailer-youtube-id="KYz2wyBy3kc" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span> Play Trailer
    </button>
    <a href="#myModalKYz2wyBy3kc" class="btn btn-primary movie-button-play"data-toggle="modal">Launch</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(null);" class="btn btn-primary movie-button-play" onclick="launch_modal('myModal1');">Launch Modal</a>
    <p></p><p/><p/>
</div>

<!-- Movie information Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Toy Story</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Plot</h4>
        <p>A story of a boy and his toys that come to life</p>
        <h4>Release year</h4>
        <p> 1995</p>
        <h4>Starring</h4>
        <p>Tom Hanks (Woody), Tim Allen (Buzz Lightyear)</p>
        <h4>Director</h4>
        <p>John Lasseter</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b0/Avatar-Teaser-Poster.jpg" width="220" height="342">
    <h2>Avatar</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModald1_JBMrrYw8">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> More details!
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary movie-button-play"
    data-trailer-youtube-id="d1_JBMrrYw8" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span> Play Trailer
    </button>
    <a href="#myModald1_JBMrrYw8" class="btn btn-primary movie-button-play"data-toggle="modal">Launch</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(null);" class="btn btn-primary movie-button-play" onclick="launch_modal('myModal2');">Launch Modal</a>
    <p></p><p/><p/>
</div>

<!-- Movie information Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" arialabel="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Toy Story</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Plot</h4>
        <p>A marine on an alien planet</p>
        <h4>Release year</h4>
        <p> 2009</p>
        <h4>Starring</h4>
        <p>Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver</p>
        <h4>Director</h4>
        <p>James Cameron</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code looks long, but is pretty repetitive cause is an example. The issue here is that always in both cases the very first modal is the one that pops, in this case Modal1, even when I click at the Modal2 button.
I can't come up with the reason.

Comment: in creating modal in bootstrap, just focus on data-target which is related to selector ID in <div class="modal fade" to make it work. triggering has been handled by bootstrap.js or jquery. So, you do not need to modify it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you try to trigger modal like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(null);" class="btn btn-primary movie-button-play" onclick="launch_modal('myModal2');">Launch Modal</a>
```

i think you should do something like this insted:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
Launch modal
</button>
```

From this what I see here you just try to lunch two simple modal so all javascript or jquery function for that is already there in bootstrap.min.js.